# Changing from request scope to view scope gives ManagedBeanResolver Error in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I am upgrading from Myfaces 1.2 to Myfaces 2.2.

I was getting an issue, when bean value was getting lost due to re-initialization of bean. So I tried changing the scope of bean from request scope to view scope but I am getting below error.

Error in Console:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver$5.put(ManagedBeanResolver.java:101) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.putInScope(ManagedBeanResolver.java:367) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:340) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:296) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67) [el-api.jar:2.2.FR]
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jasper-el.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185) [jasper-el.jar:7.0.39]

    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:77) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:184) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143) [myfaces-impl-2.2.2.jar]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198) [myfaces-api-2.2.2.jar]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349) [tomahawk20-1.1.10.jar]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [1.6.0_35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [1.6.0_35]
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access a view scope bean before the view is created, which is invalid. Change from request to view scope will not help. You need to solve the original problem in other way.

Comment: the application was working fine earlier when I was using JSF 1.2 with request scope. It's only after upgrading, I started facing issues snd then I changed to view scope.

Comment: View scope is not the same as request scope, so you should not do that change.

Comment: I understand that they are not same but as bean value was getting lost, i tried increasing the scope to view.

Comment: You should use one bean for store the values in view scope and other bean to deal with the request scope logic, in this case the binding to the phase listener method. In that way it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access data from the view scope bean try loading bean with data by calling a method on page pre-render event.